# What is snake sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I read somewhere online about implementing a snake sort algorithm, but I tried Googling it and searching here on Stack Overflow, but I can't find anywhere that it describes it. What exactly is Snake Sort and what would be its run time costs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Snake sort* is also called *Shear sort*: An algorithm for sorting two-dimensional arrays. It just sorts the rows and the columns of the array in turn. It has a time complexity of *`Θ(n log(n))`*.
[Ref #1](http://www.gel.usherbrooke.ca/mailhot/gei431/labos/labo2/oets_ss2.html), 
[Ref #2](http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/twodim/shear/shearsorten.htm)

Comment: Thank you, but if possible would you be able to include the algorithm on this page also please?

Comment: You have the algorithm in both links, do you need me to copy-paste?